Yoshimi on Ubuntu Studio 24.04 , effect windows fonts disappear
I'm using Yoshimi midi Synth on Ubuntu Studio 24.04 and trying to go on edit of the sound and then the effect window and the fonts first show then when I select another options the fonts disappear...

Hello to who else had this problem with Yoshimi on Ubuntu Studio 24.04, the fonts on effect windows on selecting was disappearing.
PROBLEM SOLVED
It just need to enlarge the window and the problem is solved.
